# tabularx right bar half of left bar

Tags: fancyhdr, tabularx

So I'm trying to add a table to the header of my document.  Basically I'm trying to match the style created in MS Word originally.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrule{}

\lhead{     
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X r|} 
\hline\\    
Title: Title Here & Process Instruction\\
\hline  
\end{tabularx}  
}
```

Output has a right bar that is half of the left bar:

[image]

I can't figure out why it's doing this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\hline &`  should do

Comment: remove the `\\ ` after `\hline` (and add a `%` after `\lhead{` and `\end{tabularx}` )

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you need to practice your markdown:-)

Comment: Lol I've been fighting this for a while now too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Those damned \\ characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `&` missing after `\hline` if some some explicit empty line is wanted, if no such line is requested, just remove `\\` after `\hline`

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrule{}


\lhead{%     
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X r|} 
\hline 
& \\    
Title: Title Here & Process Instruction\\
\hline  
\end{tabularx}%  
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

[image]